# Check to see if the style attribute exists with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to loop through my form inputs to check if the `style` attribute exists. I feel like I am very close to having the correct code, but something is off. I know there are only 2 inputs that have the `style` attribute, however, my code is detecting as if all 9 form elements have the `style` attribute attached.

Here is my code:

```
$("#form-builder-wrapper input").each(function() {
    var styleAttr = $("#form-builder-wrapper input").attr('style');
    if (typeof styleAttr !== typeof undefined && styleAttr !== false) {
      alert('Has style attribute');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector to achieve this:

```
$("#form-builder-wrapper input[style]").each(function() {
    alert('Has style attribute');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! How would I store each style attribute value in a variable? I tried doing this: `var styleAttr = $("#form-builder-wrapper input").attr('style');`. On the first input with the `style` attribute, it works and logs the value. However, on the second input with the `style` attribute, I am getting `undefined`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could store them in an array using `map()`, although I don't see the point. They are already stored with each element, so why not just use `$('#myInput').attr('style');` when you need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .is()

```
$("#form-builder-wrapper input").each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).is('[style]')) {
      alert('Has style attribute');
    }
});
```